# Oracle Regular Expressions - Replace all occurrence of string matching pattern

Tags: regex, oracle, replace, regexp-substr

Using Oracle regular expression particularly **regexp_substr** and **replace** functions, I'm trying to find a way to replace strings that matches the pattern. To explain better, here's a sample data.

```
<p>Hello $(KNOWN_AS),</p>

<p>Today is your lucky day. Being your birthday on $(DATE_OF_BIRTH), you have just won $1,000,000.00. To claim, go to https://www.example.com/$(KNOWN_AS),</p>

<p>Regards,<br />
Administrator</p>
```

What I want to do is replace all the strings matching the $(?) with <xsl:value-of select="?"/>. I have tried the following but it only replaces the first occurrence.

```
with t1 as ( select '<p>Hello $(KNOWN_AS),</p> <p>Today is your lucky day. Being your birthday on $(DATE_OF_BIRTH), you have just won $1,000,000.00. To claim, go to https://www.example.com/$(KNOWN_AS),</p> <p>Regards,<br /> Administrator</p>' h
              from dual
)
select replace ( h, r, replace(replace( r,'$(','<xsl:value-of select="' ),')','"/>') ) n
  from ( select h, regexp_substr( h, '\$\((.*?)\)') r
          from t1 )
```

Result:

```
<p>Hello <xsl:value-of select="KNOWN_AS"/>,</p> <p>Today is your lucky day. Being your birthday on $(DATE_OF_BIRTH), you have just won $1,000,000.00. To claim, go to https://www.example.com/<xsl:value-of select="KNOWN_AS"/>,</p> <p>Regards,<br /> Administrator</p>
```

Appreciate any suggestions on how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `regexp_replace`:

```sql
select regexp_replace(h, '\$\(([^()]*)\)', '<xsl:value-of select="\1"/>') as N from t1
```

See the [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Otl86GWu).

*Details*:

- `\$\(` - `$(` string
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value): any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.